# Missing image in generated PDF

Tags: java, itext7, html2pdf

I am trying to convert a HTML page to a PDF with the help of iText library. I do not have a lot experience and I am failing to get my image added in the PDF.

First I read a HTML template (that I use for the basis). The image is placed with the `<img>` tag as follows `<img src="http://clipartmag.com/image/iron-man-face-drawing-6.png" class="avatar-image">`. I retrieve a `Document` class from that template. I add the wanted content to the `Document` instance. Once that is done, I retrieve the html and use it to generate the PDF.

```
String resumeFilePath = String.format(RESUME_FILE_PATH, userProfileBean.getFirstname(), userProfileBean.getLastname());
            Document resumeAsHtml = createHtmlDocument(userProfileBean);
            HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(resumeAsHtml.html(), new FileOutputStream(resumeFilePath));
            File newResume = new File(resumeFilePath);
```

In the testing phase, I even created the HTML page separately to see everything is in place - `resumeAsHtml.html()`. The web page had the image in the page. But when I call

```
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(
    resumeAsHtml.html(), new FileOutputStream(resumeFilePath));
```

the created PDF is missing the image. I also get 3 errors in the logs:

```
2019-09-29 10:06:22,678 ERROR c.i.s.c.p.s.CssParserStateController:495 - The rule @keyframes is unsupported. All selectors in this rule will be ignored.
2019-09-29 10:06:22,944 ERROR c.i.s.r.r.ResourceResolver:146 - Unable to retrieve image with given base URI (file:/Users/jklancic/dev/custom/resume/) and image source path (http://clipartmag.com/image/iron-man-face-drawing-6.png)
2019-09-29 10:06:22,947 ERROR c.i.h.a.i.DefaultHtmlProcessor:356 - Worker of type com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.tags.DivTagWorker unable to process com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.tags.ImgTagWorker
```

Any idea what could be wrong? Here is the template that contains the image already:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

#resume-header {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#resume-body {
}

#clear {
    clear: both;
}

.header-left {
    width: 29%;
    height: 160px;
    float: left;
}

.header-right {
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 70%;
    height: 160px;
    float: right;
}

.header-right h1,h2,h3 {
    text-align: left;
    font-family: verdana;
}

.header-right h1 {
    color: #4065a3;
    font-size: 34px;
    margin: 5px 0px 15px 0px;
}

.header-right h2 {
    font-size: 22px;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}

.header-right h3 {
    font-size: 10px
}

.avatar-image {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 160px;
}

.info {
    margin: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 10px
}

span.section-header {
    color: #507fcc;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}

p.section-title {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
}

p.section-subtitle {
    color: #9aa3b3;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

p.text {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 10px;
}

ul.list {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding-left: 25px
}

div.web-profile {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

div.section-content {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

div.bottom-border {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #507fcc;
}

.primary {
    color: #507fcc;
}

.small-top-margin {
    margin: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.small-bottom-margin {
    margin: 15px 0px 2px 0px;
}

</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css">

</head>
<body>

<div id="resume-header">
    <div class="header-left">
        <img src="http://clipartmag.com/image/iron-man-face-drawing-6.png" class="avatar-image">
    </div>
    <div class="header-right" id="basic-info">
    </div>
    <div id="clear"></div>
</div>
<div id="resume-body">
    <div class="bottom-border" id="education-section">
        <i class="fas fa-graduation-cap primary"></i><span class="section-header">Education</span>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom-border" id="job-section">
        <i class="fas fa-briefcase primary"></i><span class="section-header">Work</span>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom-border" id="skill-section">
        <i class="fas fa-pencil-ruler primary"></i><span class="section-header">Skills</span>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

iText has a very high number of bugs. Don't comment on the version you are using, but the resource loader has several problems that must be corrected by overloading it (it doesn't know how to load images from base64, it doesn't know how to load resources with 302 redirection, ...).

In your specific case, the error indicated is:

> Unable to retrieve image with given base URI (file:/Users/jklancic/dev/custom/resume/) and image source path (http://clipartmag.com/image/iron-man-face-drawing-6.png)

This suggests that iText is trying to access the address "file:/Users/jklancic/dev/custom/resume/http://clipartmag.com/image/iron-man-face-drawing-6.png". Debug at c.i.s.r.r.ResourceResolver:146 to confirm.

If you are able to upgrade to a new version, try to do so, otherwise you should overload the resource loader to fix it.

Remember, **you should determine first the exact problem** (currently like a bad base+path combination problem), anyway, I fixed a lot of related problems implementing our custom `ITextUserAgent` as follows:

```
final ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
{
    final TextUserAgent userAgent = new TextUserAgent(renderer.getOutputDevice());
    renderer.getSharedContext().setUserAgentCallback(userAgent);
    userAgent.setSharedContext(renderer.getSharedContext());
}
```

You must to implement your custom `TextUserAgent` to fix your specific problem (iText is not free now):

```
public class TextUserAgent extends ITextUserAgent {

    public TextUserAgent(ITextOutputDevice outputDevice) {
        super(outputDevice);
    }

    @Override
    public ImageResource getImageResource(final String uri) {
        final ImageResource legacy = super.getImageResource(uri);
        if (legacy != null && legacy.getImage() != null) {
            return legacy;
        }
        return alternativeImageResource(uri);
    }
...
```

Comment: *"iText has a very high number of bugs"* - it has a number of bugs (I analyzed some of them in answers here, so I do know) but I wouldn't call that number "very high". Unless you also call the number of bugs in the major other pdf libraries "very high", in my experience you get quickly into error situations with them, too.

Comment: *"This suggests that..."* - have you verified that? If not, why do you say that? Because there are other possible interpretations of that log statement, too...

Comment: @mkl Since I had to correct a large number of them, for me they are many. But I don't know what version it is. And "I suggest that", since recovering the image is a requirement and that error indicates that you cannot recover it, it is a point that will surely have to be corrected. (Of course, "they should determine first the exact problem")

Comment: I use the newest iText library (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itext7-core/7.1.8). And I used it before with a different project to create an invoice. In the old project it worked like a charm, when I had an older library. But I will try your suggestion and let you know, once I have the time. Thanks!